# Error when using Google Sheets API Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I got a problem when I want to run the code using Google Sheets API. The error said:

> Exception: Service Google Sheets API has not been enabled for your Apps Script-managed Cloud Platform project. If you recently turned on this advanced Google service, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

But, this error only happen on the original spreadsheet and if I made a copy of the spreadsheet, then the copy of the spreadsheet can execute the code without any error. I had already check my account and the other that has responsibility for the Spreadsheet and all of them already enable the Google Sheets API. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

Most likely you have [switched to a standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_google_cloud_projects) in your original script, and `Sheets API` is not enabled for the corresponding GCP project. When you make a copy of the spreadsheet, the corresponding copied script is using a default project, not a standard one, so there's no need to enable the API there.

#### Solution:

[Enable Sheets API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api) in your GCP project. To visit the GCP project, click on the `Project settings` tab on your script and click on the `Project number`.

Alternatively, if you don't need to use a standard project, just work on any of the copies you made.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering my question! Can you give me the detail about that? Because I've just checked the project setting and it said that GCP Default

Comment: @AskingBob Can you provide a copy of the code, so I can try to replicate this? Also, how are you executing this? Is this an add-on? Are you executing your functions directly from the editor, or from some sheet menu, etc?

Comment: I execute the function directly from the editor

Comment: Can you tell how to enable the API step by step for standard project?

Comment: The code itself works fine on the copy of the spreadsheet, but not in the original spreadsheet

Comment: @AskingBob Assuming you've already selected your desired project at https://console.cloud.google.com/, you'd click the hamburger button on the top-left to display the left sidebar, and then click `APIs & services > Enabled APIs & services`. On the next screen, click `ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES`, then write `sheets api` on the search box that will show up and press enter, `Sheets API` should get listed. Click on it and then click `ENABLE`.

Comment: @lamblichus Yeah, its already enabled, but still getting the error

Comment: @AskingBob Is there a possibility to share the spreadsheet (without any sensitive information) so this can be investigated further? There's no way for me to reproduce this behavior. Also, (1) is this a bound script?, (2) are you using explicit scopes?, (3) are you using the advanced sheets service or the API directly via UrlFetchApp?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. The solution that I do is just move the old data to the new spreadsheet and it work fine. Still don't know what is the cause of the error, but the problem have already been solved. Thank you for answering and helping my question @lamblichus!